# Trying to get "read_insights" approval from Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a webservice which will allow a Facebook user to create an account and create reports/charts of their Facebook Page insights. I am having a problem getting through the FB approval process.

I have my website working. Using my own account, I am able to sign up on my service and pull in all of my Facebook "Pages". And even report page insights on them (e.g. Fans by Country). I suspect I am able to do this since I am an "Admin" (see screen shot below):
[image: Account is an Administrator]

When Facebook did a review, it appears they used an account that did not have associated "Pages". They successfully created an account, but they state they were not able to select a profile from within my service (you pick an FB page and then can report on different Page metrics). But this is working for me.

I see there is an area where I can create "Test Users":

[image: Test Users]

And for this Test User I signed in and created a Page for it. It is my understanding these are not "Real FB Accounts". But only used for the approval process. Anyways, should I be providing FB the name of the "Test" account? And they would use this during the approval process?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's review team is also testing with these "Test Users", as you mentioned correctly those are not real Facebook accounts, rather some dummy users in an isolated system.

From my experience I would recommend you to address this problem to the Facebook developer group on Facebook itself. There are some reviewers from Facebook around who help you very quickly.

Here you go: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/